# How to turn off Torch when leaving (segue) from view?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have made an app that utilizes Torch. I have a button that turns torch on / off. However, if user turns torch on, then navigates away from view, torch stays on. User must navigate back to view to turn off. What I want is for the torch to turn off automatically when user navigates away from page.

Using Xcode 5.1.1; ios 7; this app primarily for iPhone

Here is the code I use for Torch:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize btnFlash;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)btnFlashOnClicked:(id)sender
{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if ([flashLight isTorchAvailable] && [flashLight     isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn])
    {
        BOOL success = [flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil];
        if (success)
        {
            if ([flashLight isTorchActive])
            {
                [btnFlash setTitle:@"Light On" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
            }
            else
            {
                [btnFlash setTitle:@"Light Off" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [flashLight setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
            }
            [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

Comment: Do you know the selector called when the view disappears?  If so you have your hook...

Comment: See `viewWillDisappear:`.

Comment: Okay, I looked at ViewWillDisappear but I am unclear how to implement it. Can you be more specific, @trojanfoe  ? I really appreciate your help, I am noob :) –

Comment: @rmaddy  Okay, I looked at ViewWillDisappear but I am unclear on how to implement it. Can you be more specific? I really appreciate your help, I am noob :)

Answer (score 1):

OK, break down the functionality into methods that allow easy querying of the current light state and methods to turn it on or off:

```
- (AVCaptureDevice *)flashLight
{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
    if (![flashLight isTorchAvailable] ||
        ![flashLight isTorchModeSupported:AVCaptureTorchModeOn]) {
        flashLight = nil;
    }
    return flashLight;
}

- (BOOL)isLightOn
{
    BOOL isOn = NO;
    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [self flashLight];
    if ([flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
        isOn = [flashLight isTorchActive];
        [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
    }
    return isOn;
}

- (void)turnLightOn:(BOOL)on
{
    AVCaptureDevice *flashLight = [self flashLight];
    if ([flashLight lockForConfiguration:nil]) {
        [flashLight setTorchMode:on ? AVCaptureTorchModeOn : AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
        [flashLight unlockForConfiguration];
    }
}
```

as that will make it easier to simply call `turnLightOn:NO` regardless of the current state and easier to manipulate in your action method:

```
- (IBAction)btnFlashOnClicked:(id)sender
{
    BOOL newState = ![self isTorchOn];
    [self turnLightOn:newState];
    [btnFlash setTitle:newState ? @"Light Off" : @"Light On"
              forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self turnLightOn:NO];
}
```

Comment: It's `viewWillDisappear:` with an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You could turn the torch off inside the method:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
```

simply paste the following in your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

[super viewDidAppear:animated];

// your code to turn the torch off goes here

}
```

Comment: Thank you all. Solution works well :) Just to point it out, in ZviBar's comment, the "code to turn torch off" is demonstrated in Trojanfoe's comment above. This code

[self turnLightOn:NO];

works because of the method above... So in other words, if you want to control something (stop something)  when leaving a view, viewWillDisappear will do that, so long as you input the code for whatever device your are controlling just below, as in the example. Hey, I may not be explaining this well, i am a noob. But this was very helpful to me.